# How to print a fix number of digits before and after the decimal point

Tags: python-3.x

I can do this to print minimum of three digits before the decimal

`print("{:03d}".format(1))`

and this to print three digits after the decimal

`print("{:0.3f}".format(1.5))`

What should I do to enable both at the same time?

Something like

`001.235`

`123.345`

`089.230`

`124.400`

Comment: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `fill` attribute and the `width` to achieve this with {:07.3f} as your format specifier:

```
>>> print("{:07.3f}".format(1.5))
001.500
>>> print("{:07.3f}".format(124.4))
124.400
>>> print("{:07.3f}".format(89.23))
089.230
>>> print("{:07.3f}".format(8119.23))
8119.230
```

This works because you want your number width to be at least 7 (1 for the decimal point, 3 for before the decimal, and 3 for after the decimal) and then you fill any preceding gaps in the width with `0`s

Comment: How do I do this in conjuction with the % sign?  {:0.2%}?

Comment: @JayK `print("{:07.3f}%".format(89.23))`. I'm assuming you mean so you can display the number as a percentage? Or do you mean how to do the same thing using old-style formatting with `%`?